# Why does Visual Studio error when linking having files included?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I don't really understand the why behind this, but I think I've figured out the what.

My brother is working on a homework project and they're using Visual Studio. He was having issues getting his project to compile. The project in question consisted of:

```
main.cpp
classes.h
class_functions.cpp
general_functions.cpp
```

They had the following import structure:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "classes.h"
#include "class_functions.cpp"
#include "general_functions.cpp"
```

**class_functions.cpp**

```
#include "classes.h"
```

**general_functions.cpp**

```
#include "classes.h"
```

He kept getting link errors when trying to compile, even though g++ would compile it just fine. So I tried via Visual Studio command prompt and `cl`. This compiled just fine, so I tried `msbuild` which (obviously?) failed. I went into the vxproj file, because hey, what is it telling `cl` that I'm not?

In the proj file it was including `classes.h`, `general_functions.cpp` and `class_functions.cpp`, as well as `main.cpp`. When I removed general and class functions, msbuild ran just fine. Put either of them back and **boom**. `classes.h` contains

```
#ifndef myclasses
#define myclasses
/* Code here */
#endif
```

And the other `.cpp` files contain similar directives.

I finally figured out how to eliminate the problem - eliminate

```
#include "general_functions.cpp"
#include "class_functions.cpp"
```

from the code base, and now Visual Studio compiles this just fine.

The question is **why**? What is the justification or possible benefits from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference between .cpp and .h files is that the .h files are usually included with the #include directive while .cpp files are included in the linking process.

The #include instruction will insert a copy of the included file in the code you are compiling, so by including the .cpp files you will compile a single source file that contains all your .cpp files. It's very bad practice but still could work.

But if you are then adding the .cpp files also in the linking step then you are adding those files a second time creating probably duplicate definitions of your functions, e.g. linker error. I think that's probably the main error (without the linker error codes I'm just guessing).

Comment: It *was* complaining about something with the linker. Why is one single source file bad practice? Isn't it all compiled to one executable anyway? Obviously if you're going for reuse I can see an issue...

Comment: It's bad practice to use #include for a .cpp file. The different file extension .h/.cpp is to differentiate between it's usage: #include file or link file. When you use #include that file is "copied" in the currently compiled .cpp file.